# How to change the color of status bar to a custom color other than light and dark in iOS 14, Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, uistatusbar

I want to change the color of status bar (battery percentage, time and wifi, etc) to a custom color (red, yellow, blue, etc) other than `.lightContent` and `.darkContent` that Apple offers. Is that even possible to do so? if yes please help me to solve this problem. I have seen the answers on google and stackoverflow, but they only change the backgroundColor mostly the deprecation of keyWindow. I am using `Swift 5 and iOS 14.4`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let app = UIApplication.shared
    let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = app.statusBarFrame.size.height
    
    let statusbarView = UIView()
    statusbarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(statusbarView)
  
    statusbarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    statusbarView.heightAnchor
        .constraint(equalToConstant: statusBarHeight).isActive = true
    statusbarView.widthAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    statusbarView.topAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    statusbarView.centerXAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  
} else {
    let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
    statusBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

That’s it :) Do not forget to use it on viewDidLoad function.
If you are using TabBarController this code segment should be on viewWillAppear function. This is important!

Comment: thank you for you response and answer, but i dont want to change the backgroundColor, i want to change the font color of the items that are in status bar

Comment: is that even possible?